# Printing every row of dataframe to .txt in specific format

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating software that generates inputs for an electrical grid simulator. 
The simulator reads a new txt file of energy demand for each period.

I have a data frame that I want to iterate through and generate a new text file for each line.

```
         MDN    HEN     OTA   HLY     WKM  ...    TWZ   ROX    HWB   MAN    TIW
0      286.8  430.5  1398.5   0.2  1223.1  ...   91.9  79.2  178.1   0.0  232.4
1      279.3  429.3  1420.0   0.2  1230.8  ...   90.9  82.3  177.8   0.0  233.6
2      268.8  425.3  1435.0   0.2  1244.8  ...   93.6  79.0  173.9   0.0  237.2
3      261.1  417.6  1410.2   0.2  1246.6  ...   92.5  74.7  169.9   0.0  236.2
4      257.5  404.2  1386.9   0.2  1245.5  ...   90.7  69.5  166.0   0.0  237.1
      ...    ...     ...   ...     ...  ...    ...   ...    ...   ...    ...
```

However, the output I need must have a  first row that is simply 1\n before writing the row otherwise the simulator will not read the file correctly.

The output needs to look like this

```
1
287.537042371199 431.649568377806 1402.33325378508 0.162154563486092 1226.4793487036 133.69916571938 7.42037354420338 192.081022508012 315.482546659453 562.506743454388 168.854644175358 5.1833003364674 41.3483082932446 1144.9313428406 92.1430145439233 79.3691849819957 178.546707766296 238.475566825782 0 0
```

I have tried many ways but can't seem to get the exact format I require.
the closest of which was

```
i = 1
for index, row in oldDemand.iterrows():
      fh = open('C://Users//Tingle//OneDrive//Desktop//SWEM//demand//'+str(i) +'.txt', 'w')
      fh.write("1\n"+ str(row.values))
      i += 1
```

Which gives

```
1
[ 287.  430. 1399.    0. 1223.    7.  192.  133.  315.  561.  178.    5.
   41. 1142.   92.   79.  178.    0.  232.]
```

**However the simulator won't read this due to the square brackets**

Comment: How are you saving the output at the minute?

Comment: Hey James, I've added an answer, there is room to improve on this though if you're interested.

Comment: Turns out that my initial fix isn't working as hoped due to square brackets. Further help would be great.

Comment: `df.index = df.index.map(str) + "\n"` and `df.to_csv("test.txt", sep="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=" ")` - don't forget `import csv` too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: I added an ugly workaround using *.replace* to get rid of the brackets and new line**. 
This requires a lot of file opening and closing which isn't ideal but this task is often only performed once.

```
for index, row in oldDemand.iterrows():
              fh = open('C://Users//Tingle//OneDrive//Desktop//SWEM//demand//'+str(i) +'.txt', 'w')
              fh.write("1\n"+ str(row.values))
              fh.close()
              fh = open('C://Users//Tingle//OneDrive//Desktop//SWEM//demand//'+str(i) +'.txt', 'r')
              filedata = fh.read()
              fh.close()
              filedata = filedata.replace("[ ", "")
              filedata = filedata.replace("]", "")
              filedata = filedata.replace(".\n", ".")
              fh = open('C://Users//Tingle//OneDrive//Desktop//SWEM//demand//' + str(i) + '.txt', 'w')
              fh.write(filedata)
              fh.close()
              i += 1
       print("Demand calculations and txt file generator complete.")
```

Output

```
1
287.  430. 1399.    0. 1223.    7.  192.  133.  315.  561.  178.    5.   41. 1142.   92.   79.  178.    0.  232.
```

More elegant workarounds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a 1 in the first row you could write it first and then write your dataframe in append mode, something like this:

```py
# Create a new file with a 1 in the first line
with open('out_file.txt', 'wt') as f:
    f.write('1\n')

# Append the rest of your dataframe
df.to_csv('out_file.txt', sep='\t', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

**Edit**

If you want to run this for every row, you can put it in a for loop like this:

```py
n_rows = df.shape[0]
for i in range(n_rows):
    fname = f'file_{i}.txt'
    with open(fname, 'wt') as f:
        f.write('1\n')

    df.iloc[[i]].to_csv(fname, sep='\t', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```